Integrating TypeScript-based Tailwind Config with PostCSS inan Nx-Managed Next.js Project
I use lerna and nx for my project and use nx with command npx create-nx-workspace@latest --preset=next for creating my next.js app and use nx g @nx/react:setup-tailwind --project=my-app for setting up tailwind
nx create a tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js
I changed the tailwind.config from js to ts and this is my config
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';
const config: Config = {
  content: [
    `./src/components/**/*.{ts,tsx,mdx}`,
    `./src/app/**/*.{ts,tsx,mdx}`,
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {...myTheme},
  },
  plugins: [],
};

export default config;


and this is my postcss.config.js
const { join } = require(`path`);

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: join(__dirname, `tailwind.config.ts`),
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

everything works fine when my tailwind.config is a JS file but when i change it from JS to TS i got this error
import type { Config } from 'tailwindcss';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

also I add this config to my project.json file but nothings changed
{
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/web:webpack",
      "options": {
        "postcssConfig": "./postcss.config.js"
      }
    }
  }
}

when I init next.js with npx create-next-app I didn't see such error like this and everything works fine but with nx I got this error.
also I provide my tsconfig.json file:
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "types": ["node"],
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.jsx",
    "./tailwind.config.ts",
    "../../packages/vayu-app/.next/types/**/*.ts",
    "../../dist/packages/vayu-app/.next/types/**/*.ts",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jest.config.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.stories.ts",
    "**/*.stories.js"
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.storybook.json"
    }
  ]
}

